# How to handle null field value when using LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Table Data:

[image]

I have this sql script:

```
SELECT
    ei.objid
FROM entityindividual ei 
INNER JOIN entity e 
    ON ei.objid = e.objid
LEFT JOIN entity_address ea 
    ON ei.objid = ea.parentid
WHERE ei.gender = 'M'
AND ISNULL(ea.barangay_name) LIKE '%'
```

If you run this script, **6 records** will be displayed, but without using `ISNULL(ea.barangay_name)`, only **1 record** will be diplayed.

But consider this scenario:

```
SELECT
    ei.objid
FROM entityindividual ei 
INNER JOIN entity e 
    ON ei.objid = e.objid
LEFT JOIN entity_address ea 
    ON ei.objid = ea.parentid
WHERE ei.gender = 'M'
AND ISNULL(ea.barangay_name) LIKE '%BUENAVISTA%'
```

The **PROBLEM** is **no records** will display when you run the script above. **WHY? How to fix this one?**

Comment: what exactly are you doing here? `AND ISNULL(ea.barangay_name) LIKE '%'`

Comment: result of isnull(col) will be 1 or 0, what are you trying to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `coalesce` instead of `isnull`.

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php

```
SELECT
    ei.objid
FROM entityindividual ei 
INNER JOIN entity e 
    ON ei.objid = e.objid
LEFT JOIN entity_address ea 
    ON ei.objid = ea.parentid
WHERE ei.gender = 'M'
AND coalesce(ea.barangay_name,'') LIKE '%BUENAVISTA%'
```